# Multiple columns in Oracle view by using same function that returns object type

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Inside my view:

```
PRIMARY_KEY,
RANDOM_FUNCTION(RANDOM_PARAMETER) AS COLUMN_ONE
--other code
```

Current output of view:

| PRIMARY_KEY | COLUMN_ONE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |

Here I can generate **only one column** (`COLUMN_ONE`) by using that function.

But if I want to use a function that returns an **Object Type** (which has four attributes) in order to generate **four columns** like:

| PRIMARY_KEY | COLUMN_ONE | COLUMN_TWO | COLUMN_THREE | COLUMN_FOUR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Doctor | 123 | Dubai |

How can I do this?

Note: I want **separate columns**, **not a Dataset**.

Comment: Please post full sample data and expected output in detail.

Answer (score 4):

A simple way to achieve this is to unnest a function's result from a collection.

Consider the following [reproducible example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c976f1c22f5d24bdfc94d01045ea9dcd):

```
create table t (id, memo) as
    select 1, 'aaa'  from dual union all
    select 2, 'bbbb' from dual
/
create or replace type o force as object (len int, val varchar2(16))
/
create or replace type coll as table of o
/
create or replace function f (val varchar2) return o is
begin
    return o (length (val), substr (val, 1, 16));
end;
/
create or replace view v as
    select * from t, coll (f(t.memo))  
    --For older versions, you need to use the TABLE operator:
    --select * from t, table( coll (f(t.memo)))
/
```

Result:

```
select * from v;

        ID MEMO                    LEN VAL             
---------- ---------------- ---------- ----------------
         1 aaa                       3 aaa             
         2 bbbb                      4 bbbb
```

Answer (score 1):

You may just wrap your query with outer `select` statement and [access object properties](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions009.htm) in it. This way query plan stays "plain" and less expensive (avoided collection constructor) with correct estimates (E-rows):

> ```
> create type t1
> as object(
>   attr1 int,
>   attr2 varchar2(20),
>   attr3 date
> )
> ```

> ```
> create type t1_tab
> as table of t1
> ```

> ```
> create table t
> as
> select
>   level as id
> from dual
> connect by level < 5
> ```

> ```
> create function f(id in int)
> return t1
> as
> begin
>   return t1(id, id ||
>   '', sysdate + id);
> end;
> /
> ```

> ```
> create view v_t
> as
> with a as (
>   select
>     t.id
>     , f(t.id) as f_id
>   from t
> )
> select
>   b.id
>   , b.f_id.attr1 as f_a1
>   , b.f_id.attr2 as f_a2
>   , b.f_id.attr3 as f_a3
> from a b
> ```

> ```
> create view v_t2
> as
> select
>   *
> from t, t1_tab( f(t.id) ) b
> ```

> ```
> select /*+gather_plan_statistics*/
>   *
> from v_t
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | F_A1 | F_A2 | F_A3     
> -: | ---: | :--- | :--------
>  1 |    1 | 1    | 28-JUN-21
>  2 |    2 | 2    | 29-JUN-21
>  3 |    3 | 3    | 30-JUN-21
>  4 |    4 | 4    | 01-JUL-21
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(
>   format => 'TYPICAL ALLSTATS LAST'
> ));
> ```
>
> ```
> | PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                                             |
> | :---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | SQL_ID  d9rc13zf1azau, child number 0                                                                                         |
> | -------------------------------------                                                                                         |
> | select /*+gather_plan_statistics*/   * from v_t                                                                               |
> |                                                                                                                               |
> | Plan hash value: 1601196873                                                                                                   |
> |                                                                                                                               |
> | ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | | Id  | Operation         | Name | Starts | E-Rows |E-Bytes| Cost (%CPU)| E-Time   | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers | Reads  | |
> | ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |      1 |        |       |     3 (100)|          |      4 |00:00:00.01 |       2 |      1 | |
> | |   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| T    |      1 |      4 |    12 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |      4 |00:00:00.01 |       2 |      1 | |
> | ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> |                                                                                                                               |
> ```

> ```
> select /*+gather_plan_statistics*/
>   *
> from v_t2
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | ATTR1 | ATTR2 | ATTR3    
> -: | ----: | :---- | :--------
>  1 |     1 | 1     | 28-JUN-21
>  2 |     2 | 2     | 29-JUN-21
>  3 |     3 | 3     | 30-JUN-21
>  4 |     4 | 4     | 01-JUL-21
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(
>   format => 'TYPICAL ALLSTATS LAST'
> ));
> ```
>
> ```
> | PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                                                         |
> | :---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | SQL_ID  3u7591p8xjjq8, child number 0                                                                                                     |
> | -------------------------------------                                                                                                     |
> | select /*+gather_plan_statistics*/   * from v_t2                                                                                          |
> |                                                                                                                                           |
> | Plan hash value: 1444375322                                                                                                               |
> |                                                                                                                                           |
> | ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | | Id  | Operation                              | Name | Starts | E-Rows |E-Bytes| Cost (%CPU)| E-Time   | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers | |
> | ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                       |      |      1 |        |       |   113 (100)|          |      4 |00:00:00.01 |       2 | |
> | |   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                          |      |      1 |  32672 |   159K|   113   (0)| 00:00:01 |      4 |00:00:00.01 |       2 | |
> | |   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL                    | T    |      1 |      4 |    12 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |      4 |00:00:00.01 |       2 | |
> | |   3 |   COLLECTION ITERATOR CONSTRUCTOR FETCH|      |      4 |   8168 | 16336 |    28   (0)| 00:00:01 |      4 |00:00:00.01 |       0 | |
> | ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> |                                                                                                                                           |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=627b937964478a36da0806dbac4e05c7)*